# Difference between JavaFX and Vaadin

Tags: javafx, vaadin

I see JavaFX and Vaadin very similar except for the fact that JavaFX requires Java plugin in the browser. But otherwise it seems to offer the same capabilities. Why should I prefer Vaadin to JavaFX? Is there any case when Vaadin is a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pretty much answered it yourself. You just need to look into it a bit more. Chrome started to disable their Java related plugins which will eventually push those apps off the shelf. Who knows when/if the other browsers follow that trend.

[Chrome starts pushing Java off the web](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/04/chrome-starts-pushing-java-off-the-web-by-disabling-plugins/)

Vaadin offers many features that you can easily see for yourself in their [demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/) section. And it's in pure Java. It's still a young technology apparently, give or take 8 years old.

I'm not gonna give my personal opinion because this is not the place but I wished you would've just googled this simple query:

[Vaadin vs. JavaFX](https://vaadin.com/comparison)

Comment: FWIW I see these two as completely different. JavaFX is a UI toolkit, not a web application framework. Vaadin is a client-server framework, where the client-side is browser-based, not a thick-client app. You can still (just about) make an applet with JavaFX, but no-one has written applets in real-life for years. So, Vaadin is a reasonable choice if you are writing browser-based client-server apps, JavaFX is a reasonable choice if you are writing desktop apps (and *maybe* mobile apps).

Comment: @James_D actually it does. You just need to select it from the checkbox to see its comparison with Vaadin. It's an older version though sadly.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that, edited. But it's still comparing two essentially different things.

Comment: @James_D Apparently. Thanks for enlightening me as well. I think you should put your first comment as an answer too.